# Valor de atributo inacessível

Tags: angular, ionic, typescript

Olá, estou tentando pegar o atributo de um objeto na minha view mas não consigo, sempre que tento dá undefined

**"Controller"**
[image: Controller]

**Serviço**
[image: Serviço]

**Interface**
[image: Interface]

**View (backend)**
[image: view back]

**View Front (brownser)**
[image: View Front (brownser)]

> > Até aqui dessa forma eu consigo visualizar todo o meu objeto na minha view,  mas se eu tento acessar qualquer atributo, dá erro conforme as imagens abaixo:

**View (backend)**
[image: View Backc acessando atributo do objeto]

Na linha 11 estou tentando acessar um atributo do meu objeto criteria, mas aparece o seguinte erro:

[image: undefined]

Alguma luz no fim do túnel?
desde já sou grato

Comment: Por favor edite sua pergunta e adicione o codigo inves de prints.

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Voce esta tentando acessar uma propriedade que não foi inicializada e sera somente setada depois de um http request. Para contornar isso o jeito mais fácil e usar o ngIF

```
<ion-card *ngIf="criteria">

{{citieria.aucc_id}}
```

Comment: Por favor considere adicionar uma explicação mínima na sua resposta.

Comment: Editei, estava esperando ele postar o codigo como texto...

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema ocorre devido a você estar trabalhando com dados assincronos. Quando sua aplicação inicia, sua variavel `criterias` está indefinida, e só vai receber o valor quando o observable retornado pela `.getCustomerCritira()` estiver completo.

Assim, sua view vai tentar acessar um atributo que ainda não existe.

Se estiver com as versões mais novas do ionic, uma alternativa seria transformar sua variavel `criterias` em um fluxo de dados.

Seu .ts ficaria algo assim:

```
export class FormAuditoria {

  /* seu codigo */

  criteriasObservable: Observable<AuditCustomerCriterionInterface>;

  constructor() {
    this.criteriasObservable = this.auditCustomerCriterionProvider
      .getCustomerCriteria(this.cucr_crit_id, this.audi_id);
  }
}
```

Sua view:

```
<ion-card *ngIf="criteriasObservable | async as criterias">
    <ion-card-content>
        {{ criterias.aucc_id }}
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

:)